# I cannot get a PictureBox control in a custom control to resize properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, custom-controls, .net-4.5

I am creating a simple custom control that has 3 visual elements aligned in a column: a `Label` on top, a `PictureBox` in the middle, and another `PictureBox` at the bottom. The size of the control is 100 x 70 in the designer.

[image]

I cannot get the 2 `PictureBox` controls to resize below 100px in width. The controls are in a `TableLayoutPanel`. Each control is docked to `Fill`. The panel itself is docked to `Fill` in the design panel.

When I drop the control into a form, the `PictureBox` controls will not scale below 100px in width:
[image]

As you can see it clips the images. The height scales up and down perfectly. I have some resize code that is scaling the font size of the title.

The properties of the `PictureBox` for the port image are:

```
    this.pbCOMPort.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.pbCOMPort.Image = global::SerialTest.Properties.Resources.comport;
    this.pbCOMPort.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 17);
    this.pbCOMPort.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
    this.pbCOMPort.Name = "pbCOMPort";
    this.pbCOMPort.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 38);
    this.pbCOMPort.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    this.pbCOMPort.TabIndex = 1;
    this.pbCOMPort.TabStop = false;
```

I have tried making the image smaller in the designer, but when I manually edit the size of the `PictureBox` control to anything below 100px it immediately jumps back up to 100. I also tried resizing the control in the resize event of the `TableLayoutPanel`:

```
//resize the picture box
var pbsize = pbCOMPort.Size;
pbCOMPort.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(tableLayoutPanel1.Width, pbsize.Height);
```

But it does not work. For some reason the width will not go below 100.

Comment: Do you have a [MinimumSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.minimumsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set on your control?

Comment: Also, what are the [ColumnStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.columnstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your TableLayoutPanel set to?

Comment: I do not, as you can see from the properties list. Both the `TableLayoutPanel` and the `PictureBox`s have the default `0, 0` set for `MinimumSize`

Comment: @Idle_Mind Hey! That was it. The column width was set to 100. It seems that an absolute width of 100 on the column would still allow it to expand, but then acted as a minimum width when shrinking it. Thanks!

Comment: If you only have one column, and want it to take up the whole TableLayoutPanel width, then set it Percent (the number doesn't matter since you only have one column).